# Retrieve connected applications for an user on google admin

Tags: google-admin-sdk

On the security part of an account details we can find the Connected applications section where all the third-party applications are listed.

How can I retrieve this list via the API ou SDK ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Reports API [`tokens.list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/list). This returns a list of all active tokens (or connected apps) for a particular user. The resource looks something like this:

```js
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "admin#directory#token",
      "etag": "...",
      "clientId": "...apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "displayText": "Some app",
      "anonymous": false,
      "nativeApp": false,
      "userKey": "...",
      "scopes": [
        "https://mail.google.com/",
        "..."
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And just like the Admin console menu in your screenshot you can also revoke the tokens for each user by using [`tokens.delete`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/delete).

##### Reference:

- [Tokens.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/list)
- [Token resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens)